# LiveJournal website interface authentication

Tags: android

I need to add livejournal support to an application. I'm a bit confused about authentication means.

They're using xml-rpc which gives me an opportunity to send requests to their server, however I think that users won't type in their account details in my custom authentication form so easily - I mean I wouldn't trust just every custom form. Is there any option to authenticate user through the site interface ? If so, will it be possible to retrieve auth token in order to send "post an entry" and similar requests ?

Thanks.